# ¿Cómo enviar una imagen o archivo fijo a un input file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Deseo adjuntar un archivo a un `input` de tipo `file`, pero sin apretar el botón examinar. La idea es que cuando me cargue la página en el `$(document).ready()`, me aparezca el archivo ya adjuntado, sin tener que estar apretando el botón examinar.

Lo que he intentado hacer es lo siguiente:

```
$('#file_adj').val("../Uploaded_Files/can.txt" );
```

Pero me arroja el siguiente error en el navegador:

```
Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.
```

Cuando se trata de enviar texto, no hay problema, pero en este caso, cuando son archivos o imágenes ¿Cómo se debería hacer?

---

Normalmente paso los datos de un boton del data table al modal así:

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal_noticia_editar" data-noticiaid='<%: item.IdNoticia%>' data-titulo='<%: item.TituloNoticia%>' data-descripcion='<%: item.DescripcionNoticia%>'  class="noticia_edit">Editar</a>
```

En el evento click del modal, los recibe asi:

```
$('.noticia_edit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    NoticiaID = $(this).data('noticiaid');
    Titulo = $(this).data('titulo');
    Descripcion = $(this).data('descripcion');
    $("#modal_noticia_editar input[name=noticiaid]").val(NoticiaID);
    $("#modal_noticia_editar input[name=titulo]").val(Titulo);

    $("#modal_noticia_editar input[id=Descripcion_edit]").val(Descripcion);
});
```

pero cuando es foto, como sería?.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando es ingresar ningún problema, pero cuando es editar, esperaría lo mismo, que se cargara las imagenes

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a SOes, lo mejor que puedes hacer es incluir el código completo y no solo la línea que te genera el error

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo cargar imagenes guardadas para hacer modificación (eliminación o/y agregar)?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/2007/c%c3%b3mo-cargar-imagenes-guardadas-para-hacer-modificaci%c3%b3n-eliminaci%c3%b3n-o-y-agregar)

Comment: Porque repites la pregunta si ya resolviste el problema? sugiero que quites la pregunta

Comment: ya lo resolviste??? sino, yo te puedo ayudar

Comment: no, me conforme con la respuesta de Cesar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues, obviamente por razones de seguridad, lo que estás tratando de hacer no es permitido. Imagina que alguien tratara de hacer eso haciendo uso de jQuery en tu propia página con una ruta local como:

```
"/home/danilo/virus.sh"
```

O:

```
"C:/virus.exe"
```

Cambiar dinámicamente el nombre del archivo de un `<input type="file">` no es posible.

Comment: Muchas gracias César, eres muy amable por responder. Hice esta pregunta, con el objetivo de editar una noticia guardada y en uno de los datos, es la imagen que está guardada en binario desde la base de datos. Lo que hago es pasar los datos de un data table o tabla( similar al gridview) a un modal de boostsrap, y en uno de estos datos es la imagen. Me gustaria saber como enviar un archivo o imagen en que viene de la base de datos, para así modificar(eliminar o agregar otras).

Comment: @Danilo Que base de datos estas utilizando ? con que lenguaje programas del lado del servidor ?

Comment: Hola! bienvenido a la comunidad, algo que puedo recomendarte es que revises la documentación de Wordpress.org ( https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/ ). Cuando van a editar un post que contiene imágenes.. -> es la funcionalidad que buscas. Click: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_media_item/ Con ello tendrás la idea de como es que funciona. Espero te haya sido de utilidad el comentario, bendiciones.

Answer (score 0):

Para trabajar con archivos estamos de acuerdo que debes usar `<input type="file" ..>` ya que este permite seleccionar y enviar archivos en el post.

Ahora bien por temas de seguridad el browser limita el acceso a los recursos del cliente, por esa razon asignar el file al `type="file"` no puede realizarse.
Es mas lo que intentas realizar cuando usas la linea

```
$('#file_adj').val("../Uploaded_Files/can.txt" );
```

no se si lo has analizado, pero estas asignando un archivo que ya esta en el servidor, por lo que no se realizara un upload cuando se realice el `submit`.

En resumen lo que intentas plantear no se puede lograr y aunque se puediera no tendria sentido. Usa el `type="file"` para seleccionar los files que se quiere subir, muestra las imagenes en tags `img` y si necesitas permite que se eliminen y vuelvan a subir las imagenes, pero solo esto podrias implementar.

Asignar un archivo que ya esta en el servidor en un `input` no deberias realizarlo.