# ¿Cómo cargar imagenes guardadas para hacer modificación (eliminación o/y agregar)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy usando un *[plugin](http://develoteca.com/bootstrap-file-input-archivos-utilizando-html5/)* de [bootstrap](/questions/tagged/bootstrap), he probado para ingresar noticias con imágenes, y funciona bien, pero cuando quiero editar las imágenes, no puedo cargarla bien.

Si cargo una imagen dentro de un `div` con los datos guardados previamente en la base de datos, y si además, quiero agregar otra al presionar el botón examinar, me borra la que está guardada.

Necesito saber como cargaría imágenes en el `file input`, una cosa así se vería:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: En este caso, el input lo tengo dentro de un modal. Y cuando es texto, los cargo asi:
$("#modal_noticia_editar input[name=noticiatitulo]").val("titulo ejemplo");
pero cuando es archivo o imagen???

o existirá alguna forma de setear el boton examinar enviándole de forma fija un archivo???

Comment: Preguntas en busca de asistencia con la depuración ("**¿por qué no funciona este código?**") deben incluir cuál es el comportamiento deseado, un problema o error específico y el mínimo de código necesario para reproducirlo **en la propia pregunta**. Las preguntas sin una clara enunciación del problema no son útiles para otros usuarios. Ver: [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ya solucioné mi problema,tuve que cargar las imagenes previas con varios divs (appends) y entre otros, ademas, tuve que hacer varias modificaciones al plugin del file input para validad la inserción de imagenes.